# How do I pass a @bind-Value to a child component?

Tags: blazor

I have a parent container which I am using to wrap the bootstrap html mark up for a textbox form. I want to be able to pass the @bind-Value from `MyComponent` so that it will populate the textbox `@bind-Value`

So when I call the `MyContainer` it looks like:

```
<MyContainer @bind-Value="Model.Name" />
```

and the `MyContainer` has the following:

```
  <div class="row mb-3">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <InputText class="form-control" @bind-Value="@Value" />
    </div>
  </div>

@code
{
[Parameter]
public string? Value { get; set; }

[Parameter]
public EventCallback<TValue> ValueChanged { get; set; }

}
```

I have this basically working but when I have a form with two of these controls on it changing one blanks out the other.

Here is how I call the component from the form

```
<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <CustomValidation @ref="customValidation" />

    <MyFormTextbox @bind-TextboxValue="Model.Code" />
    <MyFormTextbox @bind-TextboxValue="Model.Description" />

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>

</EditForm>
```

Comment: `changing one blanks out the other` are you sure your not calling `@bind-value` on the same property? (`Model.Name`)

Comment: Can you provide the piece of code where you call the two instances of the Blazor component?

Comment: @T.Trassoudaine Updated question with an `<editform />`

Comment: You need to do this the right way and create your custom component by inheriting from `InputBase`. [Here is a very nice and detailed post](https://chrissainty.com/building-custom-input-components-for-blazor-using-inputbase/) that describes this approach.

Comment: Sometimes it's as simple as doing this:

`<InputText class="form-control" Value="@Value" ValueChanged="@ValueChanged" />`

Comment: @Lex - [Polite] You don't need to inherit [to do it the right way], but obviously you can.  You're just building a wrapper around the base control.  I've included inheriting from `InputText` in my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MyFormTextBox` needs to look like this.

1. You have to wire up the binding manually.
2. You need to provide the `ValueExpression` into the `InputText` so it can build a `FieldIdentifier` to use for logging changes and validation with the `EditContext`.
3. You've fixed `Value` as a string, so you must also fix the type for `ValueChanged` and `ValueExpression`.

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions

<div class="row mb-3">
    <label class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">@this.Label</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <InputText class="form-control"
                   Value=@this.Value
                   ValueChanged=@this.ValueChanged
                   ValueExpression=this.ValueExpression />
    </div>
</div>

@code
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Label { get; set; } = "Field";
    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string?>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(string? value)
        => await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
}
```

You can then use the component like this:

```cs
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit=HandleValidSubmit>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

    <MyFormTextBox Label="Code" @bind-Value="Model.Code" />
    <MyFormTextBox Label="Description" @bind-Value="Model.Description" />

    <div class="mb-3 text-end">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
    </div>
</EditForm>

<div class="alert alert-info">
    <div>Code: @this.Model.Code</div>
    <div>Description: @this.Model.Description</div>
</div>

@code {
    private ModelClass Model = new();

    private void HandleValidSubmit()
    { 
    }

    public class ModelClass
    {
        [Required] public string? Code { get; set; }
        [Required] public string? Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As you're probably going to want to add validation information into your component, here's a similar component to yours that also adds the validation messaging so you can see how that's done.

**MyInputText**

```cs
@using System.Linq.Expressions

<div class="form-floating">
    <InputText class="form-control"
               Value=@this.Value
               ValueChanged=@this.ValueChanged
               ValueExpression=this.ValueExpression />
            <label>@this.Label</label>
</div>
<ValidationMessage For=this.ValueExpression/>

@code
{
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Label { get; set; } = "Field";
    [Parameter] public string? Value { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public EventCallback<string?> ValueChanged { get; set; }
    [Parameter] public Expression<Func<string?>>? ValueExpression { get; set; }

    private async Task OnValueChanged(string? value)
        => await this.ValueChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
}
```

And the EditForm using it:

```cs
<EditForm Model="@Model" OnValidSubmit=HandleValidSubmit>
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 mb-3">
            <MyInputText Label="Code" @bind-Value="Model.Code" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-6 mb-3">
            <MyInputText Label="Description" @bind-Value="Model.Description" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 mb-3 text-end">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>
```

**Inheriting from InputText**

You can also inherit directly from `InputText` (As suggested by @Lex).  I've lifted the actual code control directly from the MS control and given you a reference to the code.

```cs
@inherits InputText

<div class="form-floating">
    @InputCode
    <label>@this.Label</label>
</div>
<ValidationMessage For=this.ValueExpression />

@code {
    [Parameter, EditorRequired] public string Label { get; set; } = "Field";

    private void OnChange(ChangeEventArgs e)
        => this.CurrentValueAsString = e.Value?.ToString();

    // Code from the InputText control
    // https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Forms/InputText.cs
    private RenderFragment InputCode => builder =>
    {
        builder.OpenElement(0, "input");
        builder.AddMultipleAttributes(1, AdditionalAttributes);
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(CssClass))
            builder.AddAttribute(2, "class", CssClass);

        builder.AddAttribute(3, "value", CurrentValueAsString);
        builder.AddAttribute(4, "onchange", EventCallback.Factory.CreateBinder<string?>(this, __value => CurrentValueAsString = __value, CurrentValueAsString));
        builder.SetUpdatesAttributeName("value");
        builder.AddElementReferenceCapture(5, __inputReference => Element = __inputReference);
        builder.CloseElement();
    };
}
```